# Why does a trailing forward-slash in linkpath make a difference in symlink() call?

Tags: linux, symlink

I'm trying to figure out a bug in some Linux application code creating symlinks. One issue I've isolated is the use of a trailing forward slash in the linkpath argument.

I have an existing directory structure /A/B/C. I want to create links to the relative directory B/C in the /A directory with the following:

```c
const char * target = "B/C";
const char * linkpath = "/A/D";
int error = 0;

int rc = symlink(target, linkpath);
if (rc < 0)
{
    error = errno;
    printf("Error creating symlink %s : %s, errno = %d\n", linkpath, strerror(error), error);
}

linkpath = "/A/E/";
rc = symlink(target, linkpath);
if (rc < 0)
{
    error = errno;
    printf("Error creating symlink %s : %s, errno = %d\n", linkpath, strerror(error), error);
}
```

The output of this is:

```
Error creating symlink /A/E/ : No such file or directory, errno = 2
```

1. Why does the trailing slash cause the call to fail?
2. Where is the source that implements this error checking?

Comment: A trailing slash means that `/A/E` has to be an existing directory.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not following. `/A/E/` is the linkpath, which does not exist yet.

Comment: You're trying to create a link with an empty name in a nonexistent directory.